# How to setup/install vtd-xml in C++ with code::blocks?

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, vtd-xml

I've been using sqlite for my project, but recently decided that xml would work better since what I need is essentially multidimensial tables. I needed something that would give random access and search capabilities for xml files, and from what I've read vtd-xml is one of the better alternatives. I downloaded ximpleware_2.11_c++.zip from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vtd-xml/files/vtd-xml/ximpleware_2.11/), dumped the files into a folder in my C::B project and tried compiling, but it gives the error:

```
C:\<redacted>\XML_test\XML_source\expr.h|275|error: 'wcsdup' was not declared in this scope
```

I tried including

```
#include <wchar.h>
```

In the file, but it didn't change anything. I don't have any experience with adding things (e.g. libraries) other than just including the headers (I have zero idea how makefiles work), so I was wondering if;

a) there's some more complicated process I have to go through to get vtd-xml working in my project, and how it might work (tutorials please).

b) There's something wrong with wcsdup that I haven't tried the right fix for yet.

Comment: what platform are you targeting your c++ code ?

Comment: Windows. I'm using Windows XP.

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: Code::Blocks Release 13.12 rev 9501 32 bit

Comment: I have no prior knowledge of this IDE. However, I downloaded it and gave it a try. did not encounter this particular issue...can you make sure that wchar.h is in the inclusion path of G++?

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Took a little googling to find out how to mess with the inclusion path, but yes, that got it working. Thanks.